# Count if cell is equal to a value in another range and the cell to the right of that equals TRUE

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How would I count all the jobs (represented by letters) that John has done in the Table 1 only if the job is listed in the table 2 as a job to count (i.e. jobs F and G). Therefore for John the total should be `2` (`2 * F`) and for Peter it would be `2` as well (`1*G and 1*F`).

[image: Excel Screenshot]

Comment: You should know by now that some display of original effort; (e.g. even a non-working formula attempt) is expected in a question. Sample data in an image that requires retyping is similarly frowned upon although yours was pretty rudimentary.

Comment: Thank you for your answer below. The reason for rudimentary sample data was to simplify my question, rather than posting a screenshot of the more complicated spreadsheet which would require further explanation to help explain what I was asking. Furthermore for brevity I thought it would be prudent not to list my failed formula. It would do nothing other than highlight my excel shortcomings, and that would only be 'beneficial' to those stackoverflow patrons that sour the community.

Comment: The main reason that original effort is helpful is that a formula (even a failed one) can often answer questions as to intent where the narrative was unclear. In this case the narrative (at least for me) was perfectly clear but that may not be true for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an array formula with CSE.

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(C5:G5, IF(D$12:D$14="y", C$12:C$14)))
```

[image]